# Why my 2nd method is slower than my 1st method?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity

I was doing leetcode problem `No. 387. First Unique Character in a String`. Given a string, find the first non-repeating character in it and return it's index. If it doesn't exist, return -1.

Examples:

```
s = "leetcode"
return 0.

s = "loveleetcode",
return 2.
```

I wrote 2 algorithm:

Method 1

```
def firstUniqChar(s):
    d = {}
    L = len(s)
    for i in range(L):
        if s[i] not in d:
            d[s[i]] = [i]
        else:
            d[s[i]].append(i)
    M = L
    for k in d:
        if len(d[k])==1:
            if d[k][0]<M:
                M = d[k][0]
    if M<L:
        return M
    else:
        return -1
```

This is very intuitive, i.e., first create a count dictionary by looping over all the char in `s` (this can also be done using one line in `collections.Counter`), then do a second loop only checking those keys whose value is a list of length 1. I think as I did 2 loops, it must have some redundant computation. So I wrote the 2nd algorithm, which I think is better than the 1st one but in the leetcode platform, the 2nd one runs much slower than the 1st one and I couldn't figure out why.

Method 2

```
def firstUniqChar(s):
    d = {}
    L = len(s)
    A = []
    for i in range(L):
        if s[i] not in d:
            d[s[i]] = i
            A.append(i)
        else:
            try:
                A.remove(d[s[i]])
            except:
                pass

    if len(A)==0:
       return -1
    else:
       return A[0]
```

The 2nd one just loop once for all char in `s`

Comment: `A.remove(...)` loops over `A`. Doing that repeatedly is expensive.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first solution is `O(n)`, but your second solution is `O(n^2)`, as method `A.remove` is looping over elements of `A`.

Comment: Thanks! I did realize that

Answer (score 1):

As others have said - using `list.remove` is quite expensive... Your use of `collections.Counter` is a good idea.

You need to scan the string *once* to find uniques. Then probably what's better is to sequentially scan it again and take the index of the first unique - that makes your potential code:

```
from collections import Counter

s = "loveleetcode"

# Build a set of unique values
unique = {ch for ch, freq in Counter(s).items() if freq == 1}
# re-iterate over the string until we first find a unique value or 
# not - default to -1 if none found
first_index = next((ix for ix, ch in enumerate(s) if ch in unique), -1)
# 2
```

Comment: I am curious in this problem, is there an even faster algorithm than O(n)? I guess not, right?

Comment: @ftxx unless there's some guarantee that the data is always consecutive when presented such as `aaabbcccddefff', then no - you have to scan the complete thing at least once

Comment: Having said that - you could probably tweak the later part to not re-iterate over the original string which might be worth it if it was very long and contained a lot of duplicated values... but no... less than O(N) isn't possible.